# Problem sending POST variable with C# client

Tags: c#, web-services, post, client

I in a C# client, I have the following code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://myserver/test.php");
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
//request.ContentType = "application/json";

string req = "er3=12";
Console.WriteLine("Req: " + req);

System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

byte[] byteData = encoder.GetBytes(req);
request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
  postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
}
```

That's calling a php test page (soon to be replaced by a rest service):

```
<?php
  echo "post vars:<br>";
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key -> $value<br>";
  }
  echo "end post vars:<br>";
?>
```

My problem is that when I run the app, in the response I get `"post vars:<br>end post vars:<br>"`, so the variable er3 is not received.

If I run a simple html form, the post variable IS correctly read.

What may be wrong or missing in the C# code ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you specify the encoding in your HTTP headers. Is the PHP page expecting ASCII encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the content type of your data so that PHP knows how to parse it.

Like this:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the standard MIME type used by web browsers when posting form data.